# Override menuitem auto close event

Tags: java, javafx-8, menuitem

I am having one menu. On clicking it I am opening a menuitem which has "search items". So there are textboxes, combo-boxes, buttons so many things which comes unders vbox.

When I click any item into vobx the menuitem is getting closed. How to stop that? If I click outside of the menuitem it should close but not inside.

Here is my fxml code:

```
<MenuButton fx:id="searchCriteriaMenu" mnemonicParsing="false"
    nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" onAction="#searchCriteriaMenu"
    styleClass="redButton" text="Search Criteria" textFill="WHITE"
    wrapText="true">
    <items>
        <MenuItem fx:id="scMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false"
            style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-margin: 0;">
            <graphic>

                <VBox fx:id="advancedSearchVbox" prefHeight="406.0" prefWidth="359.0"
                    style="-fx-font-weight: bold;">
                    <children>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="615.0"
                            prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="noborder">
                            <children>

                                <HBox layoutY="76.0" minHeight="168.0" minWidth="345.0"
                                    prefHeight="168.0" prefWidth="357.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="230.0"
                                            minWidth="355.0" prefHeight="216.0" prefWidth="355.0"
                                            vbarPolicy="AS_NEEDED">
                                            <content>
                                                <VBox fx:id="userSelectedValues" fillWidth="true"
                                                    layoutY="5.0" maxWidth="355.0">
                                                </VBox>
                                            </content>
                                        </ScrollPane>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <Group layoutY="-100.0">
                                    <children>

                                        <HBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="350.0" prefHeight="35.0"
                                            prefWidth="348.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Text layoutX="7.0" layoutY="335.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE"
                                                    strokeWidth="0.0" text="Template Name">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets right="5.0" top="9.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Text>
                                                <ComboBox fx:id="templateNameComboBox" layoutX="94.0"
                                                    layoutY="330.0" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Select Template Name">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="7.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>

                                        <HBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="385.0" prefHeight="35.0"
                                            prefWidth="348.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"
                                                    text="Type of template">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets top="9.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Text>
                                                <ComboBox fx:id="templateTypeComboBox" prefWidth="248.0"
                                                    promptText="Select Template Type">
                                                    <items>
                                                        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                            <String fx:value="Private" />
                                                            <String fx:value="Public" />
                                                        </FXCollections>
                                                    </items>
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="-8.0" layoutY="422.0"
                                            prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="360.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <CheckBox fx:id="defaultTemplate" mnemonicParsing="false" />
                                                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"
                                                    text="Set as a default template">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets top="3.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Text>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <HBox layoutX="5.0" layoutY="450.0" prefHeight="45.0"
                                            prefWidth="352.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSaveTemplate"
                                                    prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton"
                                                    text="Save Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onEditTemplate"
                                                    prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton"
                                                    text="Edit Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Button>
                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDeleteTemplate"
                                                    prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton"
                                                    text="Delete Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Button>
                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClearTemplate"
                                                    prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="55.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton"
                                                    text="Clear" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Button>
                                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#advancedSearch"
                                                    prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="55.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton"
                                                    text="Search">
                                                    <HBox.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                    </HBox.margin>
                                                </Button>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </children>
                                </Group>
                                <HBox layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="73.0"
                                    prefWidth="348.0">
                                    <children>

                                        <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" hgap="3.0" layoutX="6.6"
                                            layoutY="60.6" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="348.0" vgap="1.0"
                                            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-3.0"
                                            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="51.0">
                                            <columnConstraints>
                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"
                                                    maxWidth="132.99999237060547" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"
                                                    maxWidth="102.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="102.0" />
                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"
                                                    maxWidth="115.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
                                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"
                                                    maxWidth="76.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
                                                <ColumnConstraints />
                                            </columnConstraints>
                                            <rowConstraints>
                                                <RowConstraints maxHeight="140.0" minHeight="10.0"
                                                    prefHeight="24.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                <RowConstraints maxHeight="275.0" minHeight="10.0"
                                                    prefHeight="48.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                            </rowConstraints>
                                            <children>
                                                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Field"
                                                    textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="35.9765625"
                                                    GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">

                                                    <styleClass>
                                                        <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                        <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                    </styleClass>
                                                </Text>
                                                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Operator"
                                                    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">

                                                    <styleClass>
                                                        <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                        <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                    </styleClass>
                                                </Text>
                                                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Value"
                                                    GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">

                                                    <styleClass>
                                                        <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                        <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                    </styleClass>
                                                </Text>
                                                <ComboBox fx:id="fieldName" prefWidth="150.0"
                                                    promptText="Select Field" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                    <items>
                                                        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                            <String fx:value="CLSMESSAGEID" />
                                                            <String fx:value="PAYMENTTYPE" />
                                                            <String fx:value="REQUESTTYPE" />
                                                            <String fx:value="VALUEDATE" />
                                                        </FXCollections>
                                                    </items>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <ComboBox fx:id="operator" prefWidth="150.0"
                                                    promptText="Select Operator" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                                                    GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                    <items>
                                                        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                            <String fx:value="IN" />
                                                            <String fx:value="NOT IN" />
                                                            <String fx:value="EQUALS" />
                                                            <String fx:value="NOT EQUALS" />
                                                            <String fx:value="LESS THAN" />
                                                            <String fx:value="LESS THAN EQUALS" />
                                                            <String fx:value="GREATER THAN" />
                                                            <String fx:value="GREATER THAN EQUALS" />
                                                        </FXCollections>
                                                    </items>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <TextField fx:id="fieldValue"
                                                    GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                <Button fx:id="addImage" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                    onAction="#addOptions" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="20.0"
                                                    styleClass="addImg" GridPane.columnIndex="3"
                                                    GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                    <GridPane.margin>
                                                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                                                    </GridPane.margin>
                                                </Button>
                                            </children>
                                        </GridPane>

                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </children>
                </VBox>


            </graphic>
        </MenuItem>
    </items>
    <HBox.margin>
        <Insets left="6.0" />
    </HBox.margin>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
    </cursor>
</MenuButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`CustomMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html) and set its `content` property to display the `VBox` with all its content. Set the `hideOnClick` property to `false`:

```
<MenuButton fx:id="searchCriteriaMenu" mnemonicParsing="false"
    nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" onAction="#searchCriteriaMenu"
    styleClass="redButton" text="Search Criteria" textFill="WHITE"
    wrapText="true">
    <items>
        <CustomMenuItem fx:id="scMenuItem" hideOnClick="false" mnemonicParsing="false"
            style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-margin: 0;">
            <content>

                <VBox fx:id="advancedSearchVbox" prefHeight="406.0" prefWidth="359.0"
                    style="-fx-font-weight: bold;">

                    <!-- etc etc etc -->
                </VBox>

            </content>
        </CustomMenuItem>
    </items>
    <!-- ... -->
</MenuButton>
```